# CSS - Fixing Style Typo Breaks Website

Tags: css, html, wordpress

Looking for a little CSS Help. I am working on a wordpress website for some friends. I was putting the child theme CSS together, and when making a floating box for a logo for IE/Safari compatability, I found a typo that will break my site if I fix it. In the CSS I have:

```
a{
    color:#bb9230;font-size:1.25em
    }
.utility-menu 
.social-link
 a:hover
    {
    color:#fff
    }
} /*EXTRA CLOSING BRACKET*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 990px){
    .site-header.sticky-not-top
        {
        position:fixed;top:-40px
        }.site-header.sticky-not-top
.logo{
    top:4px
    }

.site-header.sticky-not-top .logo
```

This is code left behind by the last guy, and if I pull this extra closing bracket out, it breaks the entire top of my site. It looks like if I remove the closing bracket, IE Processes the code at the top (site-header, etc.) as 'media all', rather than 'media only screen'... I'm a bit behind, I learned 8 years ago on HTML 3.

The full CSS is here: http://northcountrycider.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen-child-wood-theme/style.css

I have also screen shot the problem.

Issue after removing Bracket: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgNSb.png
^Tried to post a before, but I can only post 2 links and no images...

I am new to submissions on this site (search solutions all the time,) but I tried to be as thorough as possible.

Thanks for your time!

*Edit: From what I can tell it has to do with my @media screen and (min-width: 673px) Setup... Seems to be expanding that. I just don't understand what is going on there.*

Comment: Was fighting stackoverflow, due to not having enough reputation. It's there now. Also the before is here: http://i.imgur.com/Q4EzPvq.png

Comment: Also missing commas after .utility-menu and .social-link, unless that's all supposed to be one selector. In that case, should probably clean up your formatting.

Comment: Found the issue. Formatting the CSS in Notepad++, found the missing closing bracket related to the media screen code! Sorry for the clutter, I  don't know how to mark this as complete.

Comment: Add an answer showing how it was fixed, or delete the question. Either action is valid (http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The "extra" bracket is not a typo, your stylsheet uses CSS Media Queries to set different styles based on the browser window size. The closing bracket you have identified is actually closing bracket for the @media definition earlier in the file:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 673px) {
    ...
}
```

There are several more of these types with different sized in the file. The nesting allows you to define different styles for different size screen (or print etc)

You can read more about them here: [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

The closing closing spot was incorrect.

As mentioned, the

```
media screen and (min-width: 673px) {
```

Portion is correct, but the location of the closing bracket halfway through link/header formatting was causing the issue. When removing the 'extra' bracket, it would cause the entire site  to enter this formatting. similar to leaving an open comment bracket '*/' with no closing.

Answer (score 0):

First time here too.

I've read your full CSS and stated that these media queries don't have the closing bracket:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 673px)
@media only screen and (min-width: 990px)
```

Also, note that you have two media queries for min-width: 673px (one before 990px and one after). I've used an editor that highlights matching brackets, parens, etc. It could help you better seeing these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't formatted properly, there are a lot of missing ';' characters and the indentation is a bit off  - which additionally put you at risk for glitches.

If you reformat, in most code programs you can "fold" and ensure everything is nested properly and troubleshoot all of the issues pretty easily. The double bracket looks like it's the closing bracket of an above media query, if I'd have to guess form what's posted above.

To illustrate, the second media query in your snipped should look like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 990px) {

  .site-header.sticky-not-top {

    position:fixed;
    top:-40px;

    }

  .site-header.sticky-not-top .logo{

    top:4px;

  }

}
```

Hope that helps!